# typescript compiler ignoring output directory

Tags: typescript

I have the following in my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "build",
        "removeComments": false
    }
}
```

This is my project:

[image: Example_]

However, running `tsc example.ts` in VS Code outputs `example.js` in the root directory and not build. How can I fix this?

Comment: From [the docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html): "When input files are specified on the command line, `tsconfig.json` files are ignored."

Comment: Is there a way to only compile a single `.ts` file at a time without ignoring `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I always use a `tsconfig.json` file. I don't know what your use case is, but it's easy to use the `extends` feature of `tsconfig.json` files to create a second configuration file that extends the first and includes only the file you want to compile in the `files` setting.